# Designing methods to manipulate an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, design-patterns

I need to write a program that:

1. asks the user for an input
2. stores those inputs in an array
3. shows all the given inputs as a list
4. asks the user which input to delete

The user is supposed to have freedom to run all those function multiple times and in random order.

***Now, the question is where and how should I implement the array that stores all those values?***

I don't know how to implement the array, so that it's easy accesible for all those functions for manipulation. I started to design the functions, and below there is my idea how to approach the problem, but feel free to change my design.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getInput();
void showArray();
void removeEntry();


int main(){

    // The array of entries here?

    while (option != 'x'){
        switch (option){
            case 'i':
            getInput();
            break;

            case 's':
            showArray();
            break;

            case 'r':
            removeEntry();
            break;
        }

    /* Should I have more functions? */

    return 0;
}

/* Asks user for an entry. Should it be void or int? */
void getInput(){
// Implementation goes here
}

/* Displays all entries that were put in the array */
void showArray(){
// Implementation goes here
}

    

/* Iterates through the array and removes given entry */
void removeEntry(){
// Implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: You can declare it in the `main()` function, and then pass it as an argument to the functions that process each action.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use an array? This seems like a classic application for a linked list, and dynamic allocation of list entries. Get ready to get your hands dirty with pointers and memory management - they are among the harder aspects of programming, but using C and getting familiar with them will make you a better programmer than using a language where you don't need to understand such things.

Answer (score 0):

How to declare an array? First question is - how many entries will it have. Easiest is fixed size, so lets arbitrarily choose 10

```
 int array[10];
```

creates the array.

Second question - where to declare it? Two choices

- declare outside all functions, this creates a global thats accessible by all functions, no parameter passing is required
- declare in main. Now you have to pass it to all the functions that have to operate on it.

There are pluses and minuses to both. Generally globals are considered 'bad' because you cannot tell just by looking at function call if they will change the data (here its easy to see but in a 20,000 line program not so much). Why not do both, just to see the difference

global looks like this

```
  int array[10];
  int main(){
     ....
```

declare in main looks like thins

```
  int main(){
     int array[10];
     ....
```